# Error setting up application container with kubectl?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am learning kubernetes and one of the things that I have been trying to do is to locally set up the pods using minikube. The problem I am facing is getting the app container to run. When I try to exec into the container, I get the following error that the container is not found, even though when I do docker images inside minikube, I can see that the image is there.

application/deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: collectstatic
          image: surajitdas001/djangokubernetes
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["python", "manage.py", "collectstatic", "--noinput"]
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: django-secrets
            - configMapRef:
                name: django-config
          volumeMounts:
            - name: staticfiles
              mountPath: /static/
      containers:
        - name: djangokubernetes
          image: surajitdas001/djangokubernetes
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: django-secrets
            - configMapRef:
                name: django-config
          volumeMounts:
            - name: staticfiles
              mountPath: /static/
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-conf
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
              readOnly: true
            - name: staticfiles
              mountPath: /static/
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-conf
          configMap:
            name: nginx-conf
        - name: staticfiles
          emptyDir: {}
```

application/secret.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: django-secrets
type: Opaque
data:
  SECRET_KEY: dGVzdF9zZWNyZXQ=
  DATABASE_NAME: ZXRs
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: cG9zdGdyZXM=
```

docker images

```
REPOSITORY                                TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
surajitdas001/djangokubernetes            1.0       88e89267c5b0   3 days ago      1.12GB

 kubectl exec -it app-deployment-5fb8b55c54-gncff -- /bin/bash

Defaulted container "djangokubernetes" out of: djangokubernetes, nginx, collectstatic (init)
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("djangokubernetes")
```

Comment: Is the container actually running?

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? Did it help you solve problems? If yes, Please consider accepting and upvoting it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `container not found` error code generally indicates that kubectl can’t establish communication with the pod or container you are trying to interact with. This could be because the pod isn’t ready to receive commands yet.

The problem may be that the container hasn't been started. When debugging deployment issues with a container, it is advisable to interact directly with its pod, as it represents the closest unit of deployment to the container. To identify the pod with the help of below commands:

```
kubectl describe pod <podname>

kubectl logs <podname>
```

Also check whether the pod exists in the correct namespace by the following command. If there is no namespace specified,Kubectl commands would run against objects in the default namespace.

```
  Kubectl get pods –namespace <namespace name>
```

The reasons for this error might be known based on output of above commands, you can check the below resolution steps :

1. Once the pod is identified, You can determine whether the pod is in ready state to accept connections.
2. This could be also due to a pod eviction resulting from lack of resources.
3. There is a possibility of network issues or because the pod doesn’t exist. Also refer to the Datree Article by Azeez Lukman for more information.

Also refer to the Datree [Article](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-error-codes-container-not-found#anchor1) by Azeez Lukman for more information.